# Source image and UIImage are different sizes

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage, png

So I'm animating a set of images using a UIImageView.  It works, but things are resizing oddly.  I initialize everything within my extended UIImageView class like so:

```
tImage = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png",tName]];
self = [self initWithImage: tImage];

NSMutableArray *frameArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
UIImage *tFrame;

    for(int i = 1; i < prp.frames + 1; i++) {
        tFrame = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d.png", tName, i]];
        [frameArray addObject:tFrame];
    }

CGRect cropRect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, tFrame.size.width, tFrame.size.height);
self.bounds = cropRect;
[self setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
self.clipsToBounds = YES;

[self setAnimationImages:frameArray];
[self setAnimationDuration:prp.frameDur];
[self startAnimating];
```

Where `prp.frames` and `prp.frameDur` are values I'm passing in from a struct of custom properties.

The problem I'm having is that the size of the images is different at each stage.  My source images are all 59x47.  tImage (UIImage) is set as 46x26 (checking the size.width and size.height properties).  tFrame (UIImage) is set as 53x35 (checking the same properties).  Does anyone have a clue why this would be happening?  Why doesn't it initialize as the original image size (59x47) and why would the two UIImage objects based on them be different from each other??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out on my own.  I had changed the source image used with tImage from a 46x26 size to 59x47 by replacing it (same image name between both).  It was still using the 46x26 image, in a cache or something I guess.  I fixed it by Cleaning and Rebuilding the project.  All is well.  So this can be closed or whatever.